# message.reply() is not working! while having 'application permissions' by admin for mail.read & mail.send (Graph API)

Tags: python, azure, graph

I have application permissions to call graph API for 'mail.read' and 'mail.send'. I am able to read mails and send new mails but not able to reply. Below issue is coming:

Client Error: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/geetanjali.sharma@nxxx.com/messages/AAMkAGFiYTcwOWM1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/createReplyAll | Error Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Whereas i am able to reply in case of delegated permissions(Python).

Below is my code for reply on a mail:

```
mailbox = account.mailbox(resource = 'geetanjali.sharma@xxxxx.com')
test_mailbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name="Inbox")
query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('internet_message_id').contains(mail_id)
for message in test_mailbox.get_messages(1,query=query):
    reply_msg = message.reply()
    reply_msg.body = "Reply body"
    reply_msg.send()
```

Kindly give your suggestions, where am i missing ?

Comment: According to the error, you call Microsoft graph `createReplyAll` endpoint, so you need to provide `Mail.ReadWrite` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreplyall?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, The method `message.reply()` with module O365  has one parameter `to_all`. Its default value is `true`. So if you do not provide the parameter's value when you call the method,  the method will use the default value and call the endpoint `/messages/{id}/createReplyAll`. When we call the endpoint, we need to provide `Mail.ReadWrite` permissions.

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/O365/python-o365/blob/master/O365/message.py) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreplyall?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)